# How to connect to a MySQL database in java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

i have a Mysql database named "patterns" created in netbeans and i want know how to connect a database in java .

---

From a comment further down

```
public MyDBConnection() { } 
public void init(){ 
  try{ 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver"); 
    myConnection=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost/patterns","root", "foufa" );
  } catch(Exception e){ 
    System.out.println("Failed to get connection"); 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
}
```

i tried this but it prints out "Failed to get connection"

Comment: What have you tried so far? And there are tons of tutorials on Google, and if you fail or struggle then we're here to help.

Comment: There's a million tutorials on the web. Start here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: Voting for reopen because **now** it starts to be a real question/problem (added some text from a comment further down)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [JDBC trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) of the Java tutorial.

Comment: Knowing the keyword "jdbc" is essential for finding a solution. A very helpful answer.

Comment: @Andreas_D: I'd say knowing Google is enough.

Comment: public MyDBConnection() {

    }

    public void init(){

       try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        myConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/patterns","root", "foufa"
                );
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed to get connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
i tried this but it prints out "Failed to get connection"

Comment: Your exception doesn't tell us much. What does your `e.printStackTrace()` show? Also, I would suggest creating a new question if you have issues connecting.

Comment: @musiKk: I'd say, you have to know *what* to ask first. I agree that "java mysql" would show millions of search result but then again you have to know that you should focus on answers containing "jdbc". *Now* fayza knows.